# How do I create a new record with Ember Data and immediately add it to a hasMany attribute on another record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember is fun but the documentation sure is thin.

I'm successfully displaying a hierarchy of Ember Data records, and now I want to allow the user to add new children (people) within the context of a parent (department).

I would have thought the code below would work, but it doesn't.  While the newPerson is added to the data store, the person is not added to the department and I get errors in the console.  Bonus for this question would be info on how to interpret Ember Data errors, as they're quite opaque.  I can't even figure out which part of them to Google.  Here I *think* the relevant part of the error is `Promise.prototype._onError`.

```
    addPerson(deptid) {
        var newID = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
        var newPerson = this.store.createRecord('person', {
            name: "Person Name",
            id: newID,
            devices: []
        }).save();

        this.store.find('department', deptid).then(function (department) {
            department.pushObject(newPerson);
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you want to `pushObject` on the `department` record.  `pushObject` is equivalent to `push` for an array, and `department` is an individual record.  You probably want to grab the `hasMany` collection on the department record and use `pushObject on it.

```
    var newPerson = this.store.createRecord('person', {
        name: "Person Name",
        id: newID,
        devices: []
    });
    newPerson.save();

    this.store.find('department', deptid).then(function (department) {
        department.get('peeps').pushObject(newPerson);
    });
```

Comment: Doh!  Of course.  Your suggestion eliminated the error but created a new one.  The console output for this one includes such things as "assertPolymorphicType" and "notifyRecordRelationshipAdded".  But my department model definitely includes `peeps: DS.hasMany('person')`.

Comment: Whoops, we're trying to add the promise (which is returned from the save method), and not the record.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!